# DjangoCMS: How to create a placeholder within a plugin

Tags: django, django-cms

I am creating a plugin called `InformationBox`. An information box contains a header, main body, and a footer. The header and footer are just `CharField`s. Originally I had the body as a CKEditor plugin `HTMLField`, however, I cannot use the djangocms-column plugin (and others) within that `HTMLField`.

Currently I have in my `models.py`:

```
class InformationBoxModel(CMSPlugin):
    header = models.CharField(_("header"), max_length=100)
    footer = models.TextField(_("footer"), default='', blank=True)
    text_field_placeholder = PlaceholderField('text_field_placeholder')
```

With a simple template of:

```
{% load cms_tags %}

<section class="box padding">
    <h2>{{ box.header }}</h2>
    <div>{% render_placeholder box.text_field_placeholder %}</div>
    <div class="footer"><p>{{ box.footer }}</p></div>
</section>
```

I can see in the Chrome element inspector that there is, in fact, a placeholder class for the `text_field_placeholder` div, however, I can't double-click to edit.

My Question:

1. Why can't I click-to-edit the placeholder inside of the plugin?
2. Is this the right way to go about what I am trying to achieve?
3. Is there a better way to create a widget (helping the user creating styled "boxes" and such)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using 3.0+ you can use plugins inside plugins. So you can have a box plugin and put inside a text or picture plugin.

http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extending_cms/custom_plugins.html#allow-children